# Error with import from self-created npm module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend

I have created npm module with some Material Ui code with using webpack. I have installed it in my project with the help of comand **npm link react-templates**. But after successful downloading because of some reason I can't import it. Here is the link to my Github with that npm module https://github.com/Volbeck/Reacttemplates.git